How to organize multi-layer data in Orange Data Mining?
I have data in the form of a MATLAB cell array in which:
Rows are individual ROIs
columns are image channels
But each element of each column stores not only the mean intensity value of the ROI, but also the percent area coverage of that channel for each ROI.
I can export this data to csv or xlsx format, but I'm not sure of the format. Should I make two rows for each ROI (one to store the intensity value, and another to store the percent coverage)? Or should I keep a single row for each ROI and then just concatenate the intensity columns horizontally with the percent area coverage? Or making two separate files and importing them both, then linking them together somehow in Orange?
Essentially, I'd like to create UMAPs etc based on the channel intensity profile for each ROI and be able to segment it and visualize how well the clusters correspond to percent area coverage. Basically analyzing these two variables separately
